# Show that some power of $x^9 - 3y^3 + 4 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]$ belongs to the ideal $(x^2 - y, 2x^2 - xy^2)$ using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I want to show that some power of the polynomial $x^9 - 3y^3 + 4$ belongs to the ideal $I=(x^2 - y, 2x^2 -xy^2) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]$.

I have done these problems for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz but I am a bit confused because now we have an additional variable $\frac{1}{y}$ and I don't know how this affects the usual argument.

My attempt:

We want to compute when $x^2 - y = 0$ and $2x^2 - xy^2 = 0$. The first equation tells us that $x^2 = y$ and the second equation tells us that $y(2-xy) = 0$ so $y=0$ or $xy = 2$. Thus, the four solutions I get are $V(I) = \{ (0,0), (\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}),(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega, \sqrt[3]{4} \omega^2),(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2, \sqrt[3]{4} \omega) \}$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i /3}$. I checked that the latter three solutions in $V(I)$ solves for the polynomial but $(0,0)$ does not solve for the polynomial so I am doing something wrong.

My question: Is $(0,0)\not\in V(I)$ because of the $\frac{1}{y}$ variable which cannot have $y=0$? If my intuition is correct, how should I go about these problems? What is the $\frac{1}{y}$ extra variable really capturing?

**EDIT** Second attempt:

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^9 - 3y^3 + 4 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and $\overline{f} = x^9 - 3y^3 + 4 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]$ to clearly distinguish these two polynomials. Our problem statement asks if $\overline{f} \in \sqrt{I}$ where $I=(x^2 - y , 2x^2 - xy^2) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]$.

Since $\mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]\cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(yz-1)$, the problem statement is equivalent to showing that $f\in \sqrt{J}$ where $J=(x^2 - y, 2x^2 - xy^2, yz - 1) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$. (???)

It is easy to check that the variety is $V(J) = \{ (x,x^2,x^{-2})\in \mathbb{C}^3 : x^3 = 2 \}$. Thus, we can check that $f(x,x^2,x^{-2}) = x^9 - 3(x^2)^3 + 4 = (x^3)^3 - 3(x^3)^2 + 4 = 2^3 - 3(2)^2 + 4 = 0$. Thus, by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $f \in \sqrt{J}$.

Is what I wrote in (???) a correct statement?

Comment: Adjoining $1/y$ is equivalent to adjoining $z$ and modding out by $zy -1 = 0$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Ah, so $\mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]\cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/J$ where $J= (yz-1)$. Therefore, should I be thinking about this problem as studying the variety of $I=(yz-1, x^2 - y , 2x^2 - xy^2) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and thus to satisfy $yz-1 = 0$ we have $y\neq 0$ and apply the usual proof involving Nullstellensatz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,\frac{1}{y}]$, let $f=x^9-3y^3+4$, and let the ideal $I$ be given by
$I=(x^2-y,2x^2-xy^2)$.

**Claim:**$\;f\in I$.

**Proof:**

We have
\begin{align*}
&
2x^2\equiv xy^2\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2y\equiv xy^2\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2\equiv xy\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2\equiv x^3\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
&
2\equiv xy\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
8\equiv x^3y^3\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
8\equiv 2y^3\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
4\equiv y^3\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
&
f=x^9-3y^3+4
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
f=(x^3)^3-3y^3+4
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
f\equiv 2^3-3{\,\cdot\,}4+4\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
f\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;I)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $f\in I$, as claimed.

Comment: This is helpful, but I am hoping to find a solution that relies on Hilbert's Nullstellensatz :( I edited my question with a second attempt

Answer (score 0):

Hint: substitute $x^2$ instead of $y$ all across, and end up checking some divisibility of polynomials in $x$.